# Getting Google+ Hangouts to work on a Cr-48

Tags: google-chrome-os, cr-48, google-plus

I have a Cr-48 Chromebook (currently on the beta channel version 13.0.782.43).

Whenever I attempt to use the Hangout feature of [Google+](http://plus.google.com) I am prompted to download the *Google Voice and Video Plugin*.

This plugin is for Windows, Mac OS 10.5+ or Linux. While Chrome OS is built on a Linux kernel, it's not full-blown Linux and I can't run the EXE file I am being asked to download.

What can I do to get Hangout to work correctly on my Cr-48? Is there an Extension I need? My web searches have thus far been fruitless.

Comment: Guess you have to wait until Google+ goes public, and CR48 users receive the updates.

Comment: you're obviously not downloading the Linux one. EXE's don't work on Linux.

Comment: @Mark: I'm not offered a choice.

Comment: Well if Google is having you download a .exe for Linux, they've really screwed up.

Comment: Heard back on the Google+ forums. Google is aware of the problem and hopes to have a fix "soon".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if they updated Chrome or the plugin, but everything works just fine now. I didn't need to do anything.